# head detached at commit. Need to put on master branch

Tags: git, branch

I have some stuff I have been working on and I have managed to get the 'head detached at commit' error. I need to put the commit back on the master branch as I have no other copy of my work and I cant risk losing it.... Really scared to lose my work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A commit with no branch.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469839/a-commit-with-no-branch)

Answer (score 2):

First: add a branch at your current commit, so you won't loose any code

```
git checkout -b save
```

Then: you need to merge this work with your `master`.
You may be in one of these 2 situations
(Check with `gitk --all`)

Case 1

```
A--B--C  master
    \
      D  save
```

Just `rebase` your work on `master`

```
git rebase master


A--B--C--D  master, save
```

Case 2

```
        master
       /
A--B--C--D save
```

You just have to move your `master` on `save`

```
git branch -f master
git checkout master
```

or

```
git checkout master
git merge save


           master
          /
A--B--C--D save
```

Comment: Thank you for this crystal-clear guide. Came in very handy for me today. I wonder why the asker never really came round to "accepting" it.