# Getting back code from detached commit with no branch

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have a commit that is not in a branch and it contains all my latest work.

I need to add it to the master branch. How can I do this?

`git status` shows this:

```
* (detached from) b225b49
  master
  saved-work
```

Will I lose it if I `git checkout master`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're in what git calls "detached HEAD" state.

There's a super-easy way to recover:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

creates the new branch `newbranch` and puts you on it, at the current commit (i.e., nothing changes except that you're now "on" a branch named `newbranch`).  You can then do whatever you like on the new branch (add more commits, whatever) and then merge it into some other branch, or whatever else you need to do.

Comment: Far simpler! Great :)

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

## Creating a new branch with the recent changes committed to that branch (your no branch) and also checkout to that branch (newbranch)

```
git push origin master
```

## Pushes the changes to master branch

Comment: That push is quite unrelated and not necessary. Just `git checkout master`, then `git merge newbranch` (probably a fast forward).